# Vscode (Mac OS) has different $PATH when running tasks

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-tasks

I am trying to write an auto task to help me build go plugin. The task looks like this

```
        {
            "label": "compile wc.go",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "go",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "-buildmode=plugin",
                "-gcflags='all=-N -l'",
                "../mrapps/wc.go"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main",
            }
        }
```

When I ran it, terminal shows the following error:

```
> Executing task: go build -buildmode=plugin -gcflags='all=-N -l' ../mrapps/wc.go <

/bin/bash: go: command not found
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'go build -buildmode=plugin -gcflags='all=-N -l' ../mrapps/wc.go'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).
```

The command go env works perfectly on integrated terminals when I ran it

```
(base) XIEs-MacBook-Pro:6.824 j$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
...enter code here
```

I've been searching for answers, but none.

I tried another task

```
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo $PATH",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main"
            }
        }
```

which prints my PATH, which is clearly different from the one I got in bash or integrated terminals.

And I also tried open a python interpreter by task, which yields a python 2.7, definately not the default one (by which python).

Answer (score 1):

You probably should set `Run as login shell` so all variables in the `bash_profile(rc)` will be exported. AFAIK here is the setting `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"]` .

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx` as @Зелёный suggest, or you also can set up `terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx` to point to `/bin/bash`.